# Reopen question about "how to get the how many times an R package has been downloaded"

Tags: support, specific-question, reopen-closed

I'm just following [these](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/36423/389220) instructions, first time raising a request of this type so hopefully getting it right.

[Check how many downloads a CRAN package has?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40835078/check-how-many-times-a-package-was-installed-from-cran) seems like a reasonable question (I edited and reworded from 'is X possible' to 'how do you do X').

It is a fairly common question, and it has some concrete (not wafty or subjective) answers.

Comment: Usually pretty pointless to close a question after two years.  But this goes wrong when the question gets a new answer ([now deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52657578/17034)), then a [chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/90230?m=44168887#44168887) gets involved  and that almost always seals its fate.  Not so sure it matters to reopen it, the odds it gets deleted ought to be low.  Let us know if it does.

Comment: (Nato) means that the question was encountered in the "New Answer To Old Question" list in the 10k tools. See the [SOCVR FAQ](https://socvr.org/faq#what-should-request-reasons-contain). In general, questions that are answered solely by a link to another website/tool/... are not a good fit for StackOverflow.

Comment: @KevinB There were two reasons I ended up at that question. i) When looking for a library to do X, I want to make sure I go with the best library. If one has 1k downloads and another has 1m, I know which one I'm going with (safety in numbers). So it directly affects code. ii) to learn of 'gaps' in my knowledge; if there are libraries in the top 100 that I'm not yet aware of, I will want to at least do a little reading on them. Both these reasons show why the question is important. I guess I agree that it doesn't ask a question expressly about specific code, but around library choices

Comment: @user5783745 I agree with you that the question is interesting and might help people. But that alone doesn't means its a good or on-topic question on SO. Asking for library choices is off-topic. Asking for other off-site resources is also off-topic. Answers that are solely based on a link to another website are hard to maintain and might get useless when the target site changes.

Answer (score 4):

I don't see this question as something unique to software development. If I was thinking about what library to use, using popularity as sole metric is setting myself to potential problems (PHP is popular!!) down the road. I don't think this question has any merit, other than idle thought or maybe some mildly-interesting factoid. Otherwise, I don't see myself ever wondering "how many downloads library X had?" when I'm solving problems using R.

Comment: Noone was so lacking in nuance to say downloads (a proxy for popularity) was a sole metric, but that it's useful to know. Looking at downloads saved me once this week already, when I almost used `bigQueryR` (~30k) package, but discovered `bigrquery` (~300k). There's a huge difference in the quality and quantity of documentation between the two. Popularity isn't everything, but it actually really matters. Especially if libraries lose traction and become unsupported. That's terrible because any production software may need to be largely rewritten (especially if security is an issue).

Comment: @user5783745 well, in what way did the number of downloads helped you that couldn't help other data points? Did it help you discover bigrquery package? Why didn't you see how lacking was the documentation for bigQueryR and continued shopping? In other words, how would that number helped you decide when there are other metrics?

Comment: I googled, found tutorials, did them, and started using what I'd learned. But what was SEO'd wasn't the best

Answer (score 3):

The linked question essentially is this one:

> Where can I see simple download metrics for an R package on CRAN?

The "where" of the question is an off-site resource. The only possible answers to that question are external links. The answers it already has are of that type. Further evidenced by the fact that the answer that you want to add is of that type as well.

If the question was something like this, for example:

> How can I use Foo API to retrieve the number of downloads for Foo packages?

It would be fine. But that would be a completely different question, with completely different answers.

I don't believe the question should be reopened.